# Sequelize associate not executing from index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models, User and Connection. Spent hours trying to figure out why I couldn't make queries assuming the association was working until I finally realized that the block of code in models/index.js (beginning around line 27) that should be executing each model's associate function isn't even firing. The Else block fires and logs "Flag 1" to the console every time.

I've looked at countless other examples of model definitions and index.js files making minor changes to see if anything would fix the problem and I'm not having any luck. Totally lost. Am I missing something?

user.js

```js
'use strict';

...

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  id: { 
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
   autoIncrement: true, 
   allowNull: false, 
   primaryKey: true 
  },
  email: { 
   type: DataTypes.STRING, 
   unique: true, 
   allowNull: false,
   isEmail: true 
  },
  password: { 
   type: DataTypes.STRING 
  },
  name: { 
   type: DataTypes.STRING 
  },
  avatarUrl: { 
   type: DataTypes.STRING 
  },
  resetPasswordExpires: {
   type: DataTypes.DATE
  },
  resetPasswordToken: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  createdAt: {
   type: DataTypes.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
   type: DataTypes.DATE
  }
 }, {
  tableName: 'users',
  instanceMethods: instanceMethods,
  classMethods: {
   associate: function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Connection);
   },
   encryptPassword: function(password, cb) {
   ...
   },
   findUser: function(email, password, cb) {
   ...
   }
  },
  hooks: {
  ...
  },
  indexes: [
  ...
  ]
 });
 
 return User;
};
};
```

connection.js

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Connection = sequelize.define('Connection', {
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Connection.belongsTo(models.User);
      }
    }
  });
  return Connection;
};
```

And here is models/index.js

```js
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
 var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
 var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
 .readdirSync(__dirname)
 .filter(function(file) {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
 })
 .forEach(function(file) {
  var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
  db[model.name] = model;
 });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
 if (db[modelName].associate) {
  console.log("Flag 0")
  db[modelName].associate(db);
 } else {
  console.log("Flag 1");
 }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just kidding. Figured it out...

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html

classMethods and instanceMethods are removed.